# Ruby Mine debugger doesnt start of error SIGABRT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, debugger

I am facing an error when trying to execute a rails app in debug mode. I have an error which is saying: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
I've seen that I don't have any memory problems. Reinstalled rvm again but no result.
What the main problem might be?

Comment: Maybe a failure to assert something? Have you debugged? What did you see?

Comment: @uprego I cant start to debug.

Comment: Oh, the whole Ruby Mine crashes. Is that? What's the OS?

Comment: I can successfully run the project, but not debug it. os is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you mean the whole Ruby Mine crashes when trying to debug the project but not when trying to run it?

Comment: As you go adding details in comments you can edit those into your question, so then you can delete the corresponding comments, for the comments section to stay not too large.

Comment: details are, i am saying error when trying to execute a rails app in debug mode, if you can see in the question